# How to change spacing in between thumbnails of my Youtube home page?

Tags: youtube

I'm facing this problem of big thumbnail size on the youtube home page as given in the link.
[image: Oversized Thumbnails]

In general, the homepage used to have 4 thumbnails.
Is there a way to get a normal outlook? or Is it a Youtube's update?

***Note:*** I am not talking about `ctrl + '+'` or `ctrl + '-'`

Comment: It _does_ look like it's zoomed in. Have you tried to press `Ctrl`+`0`?

Comment: Yes, I tried ctrl +, ctrl - and ctrl 0 also. It is not about zoom in/out bro, here thumbnail size is too big. I am thinking if there any settings need to be changed ?

Answer (score 1):

I have installed following extension and it works for me. I think you should also try this.
You have to add this extension from the google web store. You will find the corresponding extension called **Youtube Classic - Restore Youtube Old Layout** from below link.

[Youtube Classic - Restore Youtube Old Layout](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/youtube-classic-restore-y/aooobjmnokciopfgejdlbnklafighoaj)